# Wamp server(3.1.0 32 bit) is not working after shutdown and start system

Tags: mysql

I have installed WampServer 3.1.0 for 32 bit operating system, and imported the Database from other laptop..and it is working fine..however when i shout down my system and login again, either wamp is not turning to green,,or not able to login to phpmyadmin to access data base getting Access denied Error..every time when i restart/shutdown my system i am facing this issue..please help on this.

when i searched for the issue "How to make Wamp to green colour from Yellow" i got solution to change port number to different value from 80.

when i shutdown my system and re login and try to work on wamp i am facing below two issues.

1. Wamp will not turn to green(all the services will not start).
2. Will not able to login to phpmyadmin to access data base(Access denied Error).

Comment: can You check whether mysql service is running by using services.msc in RUN

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, i am new to this software, can you please give me the steps how i can check " whether mysql service is running by using services.msc in RUN"

Comment: when you enter Win+R ,you can get run wizard.In that type services.msc,then you will be directed to services running curently.search mysql in that list and get the status.